# PWA studio yarn run watch:venia give error while run on server

Tags: magento2.3.1, pwa-studio

i am just trying to setup PWA studio at my server and i am getting bellow error while run bellow command
**yarn run watch:venia**

```
    cat: /home/surtexam/.config/devcert/certificate-authority/certificate.cert: No such file or directory
Error: [pwa-buildpack:Utilities:configureHost.js] Could not setup development domain:
Error: Command failed: sudo cat /home/surtexam/.config/devcert/certificate-authority/certificate.cert
cat: /home/surtexam/.config/devcert/certificate-authority/certificate.cert: No such file or directory

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:639:11)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:676:15)
    at Object.run (/home/surtexam/public_html/betaone/pwa-studio/node_modules/devcert/dist/utils.js:24:28)
    at LinuxPlatform.<anonymous> (/home/surtexam/public_html/betaone/pwa-studio/node_modules/devcert/dist/platforms/linux.js:81:35)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /home/surtexam/public_html/betaone/pwa-studio/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:107:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (/home/surtexam/public_html/betaone/pwa-studio/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:103:16)
    at LinuxPlatform.readProtectedFile (/home/surtexam/public_html/betaone/pwa-studio/node_modules/devcert/dist/platforms/linux.js:80:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/surtexam/public_html/betaone/pwa-studio/node_modules/devcert/dist/certificate-authority.js:86:48)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/surtexam/public_html/betaone/pwa-studio/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:104:62)
    at configureHost (/home/surtexam/public_html/betaone/pwa-studio/packages/pwa-buildpack/dist/Utilities/configureHost.js:165:11)
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: OLDPWD not set
```

[image]

Can any home have idea how to setup on server ? i am using bluehost VPN server for magento 2 and everything setup but not able to run **yarn run watch:venia**

Anyone please help

Comment: where are your certificates located? is that the right path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced same issue during installation in local system but it is fixed by just running twice a command in CLI.

```
yarn buildpack create-custom-origin packages/venia-concept
```

If You are on Linux than check your certificate in below directory

```
/etc/ssl
```

May be it will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have skipped the step 3, of [magento documentation](https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/#step-3-specify-the-magento-backend-server%0A), 
use

```
cp packages/venia-concept/.env.dist packages/venia-concept/.env

MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL="https://release-dev-231-npzdaky-zddsyhrdimyra.us-4.magentosite.cloud/
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow all steps mentioned here (https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/)

I also faced same issue.

Please run using sudo.

And make sure you run command using root user, as their are certain permissions needed.

- If not try deleting "node_modules" from project root and run "yarn install" again. And then same commands from root user.

Comment: are trying to set up a VPN server or localhost ? all working fine at my localhost i am getting issue only at live server

Comment: I can suggest that you may contact your server support as this certification issue is related to file permission, as I figured out previously

Comment: Are you trying with root user ?
Did you tried by running with sudo ?

In my case it got resolved when I fired same with root user..

Comment: yes i tried with root user.... but getting same error

Answer (score 2):

Run Magento in developer mode then run these commands in pwa-studio directory.

```
1. yarn run build
2. yarn run watch:venia
```