# How I can Make Live (Production) PWA Magento 2 Project?

Tags: magento2.3, pwa

I have created a sample project of **Magento 2.3.1** on my **local system** and then setup PWA studio in it.

Now, I have not found any docs/instructions to deploy it on live server for non technical user.

Currently, I am using a command **`yarn run watch:venia`** for running it on dev environment.

Please let me know is there is any **steps** to build and make **magento2 - pwa** on live to server.

Thanks

Comment: i am also facing same issue

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269986/pwa-studio-yarn-run-watchvenia-give-error-while-run-on-server

Answer (score 2):

After setup your backend URL in PWA, In pwa-studio folder run:

```
npm run build && NODE_ENV=production PORT=8000 npm run stage:venia
```

It will start the server on port 8000.

you can use process manager 2 (http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) for managing node services.

Now,

```
cd packages/venia-concept/ && NODE_ENV=production PORT=8000 node server.js
```

Now,

> create proxy to pass connection from 8000 to 80 and 443

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a PWA Studio app on the same server as Magento you need to install [magento upward connector](https://github.com/magento-research/magento2-upward-connector).

Of course it does not need to be hosted on the same server as Magento.

Comment: so if i have one live site and if i need to setup pwa so what need to do ?

Comment: You can either run the PWA on a separate node server or on the same server as Magento with magento-upward-connector

Comment: So use this one -> https://github.com/magento-research/magento2-upward-connector